# Net Plugin API not giving accurate information about connected peers

Tags: nodeos, private-blockchain, net-plugin, multi

I have a **running** EOS blockchain with a connected peer (**running**) created by following the documentation tutorial https://developers.eos.io/welcome/latest/tutorials/bios-boot-sequence. So, my config file is not on the default path. The respective files are stored on the path `/home/user/biosboot/genesis`. Now to get the Peers information using the reference of NET API Plugin, I am calling the API  https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eos/latest/nodeos/plugins/net_api_plugin/api-reference/index#operation/connections at my endpoint. It returns the list of peers connected but not with accurate values. For example:

> Genesis node

```
cleos --url http://genesisip:8889 get info
```

returns `head_block_num` as `10385207`

> Connected Peer

```
cleos --url http://connectedip:8889 get info
```

returns  `head_block_num` as `10385207`

Now On POSTMAN, I call `POST http://genesisip:8889/v1/net/connections` it returns (`***` are edited by me),

```
[
    {
        "peer": "",
        "connecting": false,
        "syncing": false,
        "last_handshake": {
            "network_version": 1207,
            "chain_id": "***",
            "node_id": "***",
            "key": "***",
            "time": "1612778978797327000",
            "token": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
            "sig": "***",
            "p2p_address": "connectedip:8888 - 540c0e9",
            "last_irreversible_block_num": 1445747,
            "last_irreversible_block_id": "***",
            "head_num": 1445748,
            "head_id": "***",
            "os": "linux",
            "agent": "\"EOS Test Agent\"",
            "generation": 3
        }
    }
]
```

All information of connected peer is completely different.`chain_id` is the same, `head_num` should be in the range of `10385207`. why `peer` is empty? Why `connecting` and `syncing` are false? Do I need to pass any parameters related to the file's path? Please help.

Comment: I'd hit up the guys in telegram here https://t.me/joinchat/DQRZHEPktgcLlyfbl-bDuQ

Answer (score 0):

if you hit that url with postman several times does the block numbers (e.g. LIB, head_number) are increasing? or you always get the same numbers?

if you always get the same numbers it means it is not syncing as the "connecting" and "syncing" values set as "false" are saying.

when you start the nodeos are there any errors printed in the console that can give clues? when you start nodeos do you start it with the net_api plugin and [net](https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eos/latest/nodeos/plugins/net_plugin/index) plugin as well?

I saw the comment pointing to a telegram channel broken link, the EOSIO Developers telegram channel correct link is: https://t.me/joinchat/0uhWYfXVpPlkNTA1

Comment: 1.No the block number is not increasing. 2. ```net_api plugin``` was added before, now I added ```--plugin eosio::net_plugin \``` in all peer ```nodeos``` files and run again. Still, it returns save output ```connecting ``` and ```syncing``` as false with incorrect blockhead number.

Comment: And all the peers are receiving blocks means they are running. No errors in the log file.

Comment: The block number is the number at the time of the connection.  it is not updated after.

Comment: hi, did you get anywhere with this? if you solved it can you please share your lessons learned, why it was not working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

The information you get from peers depends on if it is an "incoming" connection or an "outgoing" connection.  If peer A is configured to connect to peer B and peer B is configured to connect to peer A, only one of these connections will be active, the other will be marked duplicate and dropped.  All p2p connections are bi-directional, so it doesn't matter that one is dropped, but you see the difference in  what connections reports.

The block number reported is from the time the connection is established.